# 3W/6W audio amplifier using TDA2003

Tags: circuit-analysis, amplifier, audio, power-amplifier

I am trying to build an amplifier circuit using TDA2003, I found a common type of circuit for this purpose in almost all the websites. I tried building it in Multisim and after some seconds of simulation many capacitors and resistors blow up, even with 9V of power supply.

[image: Simulation Result]

You can see short-circuited capacitors and blown up resistors in the screenshot. Please tell me what I am doing wrong, I just copied it from the circuit available in the datasheet.

[image: Most basic circuit available in datasheet]

I used the TDA2030 IC for simulation because TDA2003 is not available in Multisim. Please instruct me whether the circuit is correct or not? Or there is the issue with the simulation or simulation software?

Should I try it building in practical with the same values without any risk? Please suggest any other circuit available.

Comment: TDA2030 has a different configuration. Check from the datasheet. Maybe that's because you simulate a 2030 with 2003's recommended values.

Comment: Welcome. Circuit as drawn does NOT have enough power to blow up capacitors and resistors, even if the input Vi is overloaded. Your program assumes parts will destruct under certain conditions, but I do not see this. Make sure you are emulating the right IC for this schematic.

Comment: C1 is the wrong polarity - the straight line in the polarized capacitor symbol is the positive side.

Comment: Thanks, can anyone suggest any good software having all the required components, Ex. TDA2003.

Comment: I'd use a simulator that has more resilient components.